# Hashing an element into another element with PBC

Tags: c, encryption, serialization, hash, cryptography

I want to apply a hash function on an element and convert the hash results to another element. Now I find that there is a problem with the from-hash element. That is, if I export the element with `element_to_bytes`, I cannot convert it back using `element_from_bytes` sometimes for the result being zero. Note that every time the original from-hash element seems OK.

here is my code

```
#include <pbc/pbc.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

static unsigned char IB_buffer[] = "type a\nq 8780710799663312522437781984754049815806883199414208211028653399266475630880222957078625179422662221423155858769582317459277713367317481324925129998224791\nh 12016012264891146079388821366740534204802954401251311822919615131047207289359704531102844802183906537786776\nr 730750818665451621361119245571504901405976559617\nexp2 159\nexp1 107\nsign1 1\nsign0 1";

static unsigned char ElGamal_buffer[] = "type a\nq 3482532951481000628301986563829128446394498473733574256155354161179984756582489073071203726645550500511910754640237238097789178205610570264167893261510851\nh 4765691481319237166326209176561481743805302555086541889992911935937234088304840923602596606875066432645316\nr 730750818665451459101842416367364881864821047297\nexp2 159\nexp1 63\nsign1 1\nsign0 1";

void Hash_function_2(element_t IB_e_GT_in,
                       element_t IB_e_G1_out)
{
  unsigned char buffer[130];
  unsigned char buffer_sha512[130];

  memset(buffer_sha512, '\0', 128);
  element_to_bytes(buffer, IB_e_GT_in);
  SHA512(buffer,
         element_length_in_bytes(IB_e_GT_in),
         buffer_sha512);
  element_from_bytes_x_only(IB_e_G1_out, buffer_sha512);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned char buffer[128];

  pairing_t IB_pairing;
  pairing_t ElGamal_pairing;

  element_t ElGamal_G1_g_1;
  element_t IB_G1_g2s_f_aux;

  if(pairing_init_set_str(IB_pairing, IB_buffer) == 1)
    {
      printf("init IB_pairing failed\n");
      return 0;
    }

  if(pairing_init_set_str(ElGamal_pairing, ElGamal_buffer) == 1)
    {
      printf("init ElGamal_pairing failed\n");
      return 0;
    }

  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
  pbc_random_set_file("/dev/urandom");

  element_init_G1(ElGamal_G1_g_1, ElGamal_pairing);
  element_init_G1(IB_G1_g2s_f_aux, IB_pairing);
  for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i ++)
    {
      element_random(ElGamal_G1_g_1);
      Hash_function_2(ElGamal_G1_g_1, IB_G1_g2s_f_aux);
      element_printf("%B\n-------------------------------------\n",
                     IB_G1_g2s_f_aux);
      element_to_bytes(buffer, IB_G1_g2s_f_aux);
      element_from_bytes(IB_G1_g2s_f_aux, buffer);

      element_printf("%B\n\n", IB_G1_g2s_f_aux);
    }

  element_clear(ElGamal_G1_g_1);
  element_clear(IB_G1_g2s_f_aux);
}
```

in the program `IB_pairing` is initialized from the a.param copied from the uncompressed pbc folder, and the `ElGamal_pairing` is initialized from what is generated by the `genaparam` I found in the gen folder which is the subdir of the pbc folder. Now, the code outputs like:

```
[5242744931973888357810214698891575268968713403287687987582661419271346701723916645766967288858537828347386228320848038004460401621466729428359602848496423, 118298437701476879252590762137102463858584189697768090565747590297711649473408814747936054487138480275170041397143791824953512356308426007693466456179168]
-------------------------------------
[5242744931973888357810214698891575268968713403287687987582661419271346701723916645766967288858537828347386228320848038004460401621466729428359602848496423, 118298437701476879252590762137102463858584189697768090565747590297711649473408814747936054487138480275170041397143791824953512356308426007693466456179168]

[193714737889486499072115953742998424769489264653955710164208541956541631696577272694010272524888373065658088394836551869833950180668987684845705117682787, 8322151652329772861037196194168895802696002124303037838979551092936828926180405726470751856790581079911562675895636010857792037405706584773714399060440286]
-------------------------------------
[193714737889486499072115953742998424769489264653955710164208541956541631696577272694010272524888373065658088394836551869833950180668987684845705117682787, 8322151652329772861037196194168895802696002124303037838979551092936828926180405726470751856790581079911562675895636010857792037405706584773714399060440286]

[495047649790927154331600875943865603224939234468985749770584820482607323401569786408964940026933317685852491403307110240933283586727130743485260801306123, 627545795052423626580420805178631952553532694027088981206234423727093343832432384258118298986203220359581564990411022919298680177610751000388025394726311]
-------------------------------------
O

[4542621263375384263129179574241340967482607815987619234619001482840218784253522899638100115797770929051314594382110531705620048072005886520744474015548799, 4384016080218277894585596328932412426136126888519161287653688238921459073535259513521348441520090835443816442403976291911942079711511656142926876657574119]
-------------------------------------
O

[934929446085781431564145952513276901891994909515246349081484727464551419226172557408608926404886531004238987014488635110816400458081240110773838222735035, 5961256556272620299959818693083876773102158266860051729037463651374484980756089251260880171468476182599983428188035231226059179410518065718227845688839716]
-------------------------------------
[934929446085781431564145952513276901891994909515246349081484727464551419226172557408608926404886531004238987014488635110816400458081240110773838222735035, 5961256556272620299959818693083876773102158266860051729037463651374484980756089251260880171468476182599983428188035231226059179410518065718227845688839716]

[1224204982207723555590429339348622427566172381990610842080105056584418105637718525873987892092288009728542005861184194378722664576353556137763270960705678, 8697105603647319842683626319102469751603864170995390173683250409145042732890778489498574501879021283552905344140881861126112678686800294724427908393544229]
-------------------------------------
O

[1342315162981173575284474712688478558555924987160295354118525538511370674248831922332142524449197361143668635693752430389149660122747527319388460244716267, 5267811295598008357011271549336672278507286122051296965376347558098881407861455461777989115869240838665983404311822513990301968904409996934757904037469081]
-------------------------------------
O

[4491486047832261748660536800950738994321386405877875101997492071615864965243872556818616142835048233636100898376016387452858412191123428562316075309820872, 2667680711633239882081053356855222638213416843899362660435808202909280287640739981804569477623527608695636418075471578632318931368061236784727949670086843]
-------------------------------------
[4491486047832261748660536800950738994321386405877875101997492071615864965243872556818616142835048233636100898376016387452858412191123428562316075309820872, 2667680711633239882081053356855222638213416843899362660435808202909280287640739981804569477623527608695636418075471578632318931368061236784727949670086843]
```

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 x64, pbc-0.5.14.

Comment: Thank you very much,  I'll paste the code after a while. I saw your code, but in my code elements prefixed with Elgamal and IB are assigned different pairings. I don't know if that causes the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I think I find where I was wrong, but I still don't know why it happens. I update my code and the outputs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think I find the key to this question raised by myself, but I still don't know what happened. Maybe just as what Artjom B. said:

> Maybe you somehow managed to put these elements outside of the curve.

I changed the `Hash_funcrion_2` to this:

```
void Hash_function_2(element_t IB_e_GT_in,
                     element_t IB_e_G1_out)
{
  unsigned char buffer[130];
  unsigned char buffer_sha512[130];
  int x = 0xFF;
  memset(buffer_sha512, '\0', 128);
  element_to_bytes(buffer, IB_e_GT_in);
  SHA512(buffer,
         element_length_in_bytes(IB_e_GT_in),
         buffer_sha512);

  element_from_hash(IB_e_G1_out, buffer_sha512, 64);
}
```

and everything works correctly.

Comment: OMG, how foolish I am. Thank you! When I saw the sample in pbc manual Chapter 2 I found the element_from_hash accepts a hex string, so I think maybe I need to convert the hash result into a string. But after your reminding, I think I find the correct use of this function. Thanks again.

Comment: Here's possible explanation: `element_from_bytes_x_only` reads 512 bits (default size of *type a* pairing field) from the buffer to create an integer in `Zr` (technically `Zq`), but since the integer must be smaller than `q`, not all values that SHA512 produces are valid. You can look into the source code of PBC to see if this is how `element_from_bytes_x_only` behaves.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and explanation, I will read the related code as you advice. Sincerely, I do feel grateful for your correcting my grammar and teaching me some usage of the **stackoverflow.com** by correcting my code、question and answer. I will be more careful about the regulation of this website and my English.